# I get Key does not exist as the array is empty error even though its not empty

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm struggling with my symfony form, cause when i want to use the 'class' item of the array in my twig, i get an error message

[screenshot of the dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enqDs.png)

what i dumped:

```
{% set choiceType = country.vars.attr %}
{{ dump(choiceType)}}
```

however, when i want to access it, like this:

```
{% set choiceType = country.vars.attr.class %}
{{ dump(choiceType)}}
```

i get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtA49.png)

Unfortunately i can't pass that value via just a simple variable, since this is embedded into the form's array.

Any idea why it thinks the array is empty?

Comment: You are running the code in a `for`-loop, whilst you are only dumping one record in the screenshot. Change your code to `{% set choiceType = country.vars.attr.class|default %}` to account for countries which don't have a `class` attr defined

Comment: yep, that works, thanks! :)